# PHP File Handling (Download Counter) Reading file data as a number, writing it as that plus 1

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to make a download counter in a website for a video game in PHP, but for some reason, instead of incrementing the contents of the downloadcount.txt file by 1, it takes the number, increments it, and appends it to the end of the file.  How could I just make it replace the file contents instead of appending it?

Here's the source:

```php
<?php
    ob_start();
    $newURL = 'versions/v1.0.0aplha/Dungeon1UP.zip';
    //header('Location: '.$newURL);
    //increment download counter
    $file = fopen("downloadcount.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $content = fread($file,filesize("downloadcount.txt"));
    echo $content;
    $output = (int) $content + 1;
    //$output = 'test';
    fwrite($file, $output);
    fclose($file);
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The number in the file is supposed to increase by one every time, but instead, it gives me numbers like this: `101110121011101310111012101110149.2233720368548E+189.2233720368548E+189.2233720368548E+18`

Comment: I switched from using r+ to using w+, now it just says `Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /storage/ssd3/350/10093350/public_html/downloadredirect.php on line 7`

Comment: btw, that is a number, it is `4.59685864153... × 10^221` - Would be a great download count, right? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in one of the comments, for your specific case you can use  fseek ( $file, 0 ) right before writing, such as:

```
fseek ( $file, 0 );
fwrite($file, $output);
```

Or even simpler you can rewind($file) before writing, this will ensure that the next write happens at byte 0 - ie the start of the file.

The reason why the file gets appended it is because you're opening the file in *append and truncate mode*, that is "w+". You have to open it in readwrite mode in case you do not want to reset the contents, just "r+" on your fopen, such as:

```
fopen("downloadcount.txt", "r+")
```

Just make sure the file exists before writing!

Please see fopen modes here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

And working code here:
https://bpaste.net/show/iasj

Comment: Please read about modes "place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and __truncate__ the file to zero length". What will be read if file is truncated?

Comment: w doesnt read the file, it only writes it. w+ both reads and writes the file @santamanno

Comment: And have you checked it? we already tried that. Not working. Hence we have changed the approach.

Comment: @santamanno Still no luck for you mate. Go check once. Then post the answer.

Comment: @Rahul did you try the fseek option and fopen with "w+" ?

Comment: Yes I did, still no luck. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, pls find code here and in answer too: https://bpaste.net/show/iasj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198491/discussion-between-santamanno-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1):

It will be much simpler to use `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents`:

```
// update with more precise path to file:
$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/downloadcount.txt");
echo $content;
$output = (int) $content + 1;
// by default `file_put_contents` overwrites file content
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/downloadcount.txt", $output);
```

Comment: The contents of the file are currently "1", but it didn't echo anything at all

Comment: when i make it larger it still doesnt echo anything

Comment: what does OP mean

Comment: @Superhuman checked this snippet, it works. Try to provide more detailed path to your file. OP means Original Poster (i.e. you).

Comment: I advise you to update your question with new code.

Comment: also stop saying it doesn't respond to the OP all of the answers here do @santamanno

Answer (score 1):

That appending should just be a typecasting problem, but I would not encourage you to handle counts the file way. In order to count the number of downloads for a file, it's better to make a database update of a row using [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)  to handle concurrency properly, as doing it the file way could compromise accuracy.

Comment: so you're suggesting i use sql instead?

Comment: @Superhuman Yes, imagine `2` requests for download coming at the same time? You would read `26` from a file and save it as `27`, but technically it should be `28`.

Comment: Does not respond the question of the OP and its NOT a typecasting problem

Comment: @santamanno  Ok, might be, but encouraging a wrong way isn't a solution either.

Comment: maybe i'll try doing this.  I originally thought it might be a hassle to set up an sql database for the website, but right now nothing else is working for me.

Comment: @vivek_23, right, removed downvote, but please see my working solution below

Comment: @santamanno Your downvote doesn't seem to be removed. Second, I have already mentioned that doing it the file way is not a good idea!

Comment: @vivek_23, sorry my voting is locked for a while unless you edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content, check if the file has data. If not initialise to 0 and then just replace the content.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents("downloadcount.txt");
$content     = (!empty($fileContent) ? $fileContent : 0);
$content++;
file_put_contents('downloadcount.txt', $content);
```

Check `$str` or directly content inside the file

Comment: May I know your concern mate?

Comment: Same reply as u_mulder, does not respond the question, just provides a different method for implementing the result.